# How to uninstall ArangoDB

Tags: centos7, uninstallation, arangodb

I've installed ArangoDB on a CetOS7 system and it appears to have become corrupt after stalling out mid-import. Can't reach the web page and when I boot the server it consumes all of my memory. arangosh isn't functioning correctly either. What's the best way of uninstalling/removing all Arango files so I can run a fresh installation? My first guess is to remove everything that starts with "arango" since this seems to be the naming scheme. Any tips or can anyone verify that every arango file actually begins with "arango"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure about the uninstall, but I have been running arangodb in a docker container for a while without any issues.This way you avoid any potential install problems. You can get the official image here: https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb/  Hope the helps!

Answer (score 0):

Usually `yum remove packagename` should do the trick for any package. You can try to delete the database directory in `/var/lib/arangodb` to remove a corrupted database. Please provide the exact version of your ArangoDB installation.